# In which environment does rspec execute tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

In Rails, if i run tests using rspec, will rspec automatically change the  environment to `:test` and start executing the tests? and once it complete the tests, will the environment be changed back to `:development` ? Any pointers where i can find more info on this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tests will always run in `test` unless you change it like `RAILS_ENV=development rspec spec/`

`development` is then for the server and the console.

Comment: yes, indeed; forgot to mention that you can change RAILS_ENV for console and for the server too

Comment: is there a way to run just one specific test in a development environment, and leave the rest of the tests in the test environment?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it runs in the :test environment.

It does not 'change', you can run multiple environments (e.g. you can have your development server running and executing tests on the meanwhile)